# JavaScript Error Debugging - using for loop with getElementById

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to debug JavaScript codes.
I guess I am having a problem using for loop  with getElementById.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CGPA to Percentage calculator</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function addFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("sem").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var pbtn = document.getElementById("percent");
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }

        if(number>0 && number<=8){

              for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("SGPA [Semeter " + (i+1)+ "] : "));
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.name = "sem" + i;
                    container.appendChild(input);
                    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    }

            pbtn.disabled = false;
        }
        else{
            if(number>8)
                alert("Enter a value less than 8");
            else
                alert("Enter a valid input");
        }
        }
    function percent(){
        var number = document.getElementById("sem").value;
        var sum = 0.0;
        var pcnt = 0.0;
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("sem"+i).value);
        }   
        pcent = parseFloat(sum) / parseInt(number);
        alert(pcent);
    }
    </script>
</head
<body>
    <div align ="center">Number of Semester (MAX [8]) : 
    <input type="text" id="sem" name="sem" value=""> &nbsp;
    <button type="button" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</button> &nbsp;
    <button type="button" name="percent" id="percent" onclick="percent()" disabled="disabled">Calculate %</button>
    </br></br></br>
    <div id="container"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats console's output. And what do you actually want to achieve here

Comment: check the console for errors. [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: if you are in chrome press ctrl+12 to open console for example if you want to debug function like addFileds() just type addFileds and press enter and click the code in console now you can place break point in your code just like net beans and visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I think you are generating input with a name `"sem"+i`, but you are fetching it by it's ID (which is not defined)